# How to control when to present the Bluetooth permission request prompt in iOS13?

Tags: bluetooth, alert, core-bluetooth, prompt, ios13

[image]

With the new policies related to privacy & Bluetooth in iOS13, my app launches an alert prompt on app install, or after app update (in iOS13) requesting access to Bluetooth.

Is there anyway to control the presentation of this prompt?

I'm making sure that the app doesn't access or initializes anything related to the CBCentralManager, on app start, but in a very specific place in the app, but still I get the prompt on app start.

Is the presentation of this prompt related to the CBCentralManager usage? What are the requirements for this prompt to be shown?

Comment: If you're not initializing `CBCentralManager` yet, I would open an Apple Feedback to complain about that behavior. That may not be intended. But first make sure you're not initializing the central.

Comment: Do mean that is indeed the CBCentralManager initialization what is causing the prompt to be triggered @Rob ?

Comment: That's where I would expect you to get this message.

Comment: Ok, so it's verified. The prompt message is shown on initialization of the CBCentralManager. I was initializing it, by mistake, when accessing a property of the abstraction. For people with the same issue, I will recommend to verify that there is no pod or dependency accessing CBCentralManager.